# Copy and paste the latest modified log files from one server to other server (the servers are in the different domains)

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, copy-paste

I am trying to write a script that copies the latest modified log file from one server to another server (servers are in different domains), while copying it should check for the credentials and then execute the script.

Please let me know if the script is correct or any corrections to be made.

```
$sourcePath = 'sourcepath' 
$destPath = 'Destinationpath' 
$compareDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1); 
$LastFileCaptured = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath |
                    where {$_.Extension.EndsWith('.log') -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $compareDate } |
                    Sort LastAccessTime -Descending |
                    select -First 1 |
                    select -ExcludeProperty Name, LastAccessTime
Write-Host $LastFileCaptured.Name  
$LastFileCaptured.LastAccessTime
$LastFileCaptured = Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
                    Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime.AddDays(-1) -gt (Get-Date)}
Write-Host $LastFileCaptured
Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse -Include '.log' | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") -gt (get-date).ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")
} | ForEach-Object {
    $destDir = Split-Path ($_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($sourcePath), $destPath)
    if (!(Test-Path $destDir)) {
        New-Item -ItemType directory $destDir | Out-Null
    }
    Copy-Item $_ -Destination $destDir
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include more details about your attempt. Have you tried your code on a server? and if so, what is the output you get? If we have this information, it'll be easier and faster to help you.

Comment: Does the script do what you want? If so, then it apparently is correct. If not you need to describe what you expected the script to do and what it actually does.

Comment: The script should check for an updated log file by the date modified field then copy the log file to the destination folder.
l need to pass the credentials as the servers are in different domains.
FYI...
there is one source and two destination servers.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i have updated the requirements could you please have a look and help me

Answer (score 0):

The "correctness" of your script is determined easily by running it! But, while this isn't a direct answer, I would suggest [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) for this task.

In particular note these options:

- /mon:  Monitors the source, and runs again when more than N changes are detected.
- /maxage:   Specifies the maximum file age (to exclude files older than N days or date).